# Render Animation error in Eevee: transparent frame only in animation

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, transparency, error

I am currently trying to render an animation, using Eevee, however, when I am rendering I encounter a bizzare mismatch between the imaged rendered using "Render Image" and "Render Animation"

When Rendering the image alone, the frame is rendered perfectly, without issue.

However, when rendering in the animation, after a certain frame, the image instead renders to an entirely transparent frame, with nothing visible. After this happens, every subsequent frame is rendered as transparent as well. Additionally, this frame changes depending on which frames I am rendering.

In my case:
If I render frames 241-300. at frame 273, the render fails:

Frame 272: [image: Frame 272: Working render]
Frame 273 (and all subsequent frames): [image: Frame 273: failed render]

If I render frames 273-276, the render fails at frame 275.
Frame 273, now rendered perfectly fine: [image: Frame 273: Working Render]

And if I render from 298-300, the render succeeds on all frames (no issues). So essentially, if I skip over this "corrupted region", it renders fine for the remaining frames.

For context, the part of the animation I am showing is the camera panning from one part of the scene (a building) to another (underwater). From Frames 240 to 280, the camera is moving between keyframes. The blur in the scene is due to motion blur in the render.
I am also using the compositor to overlay the render over a gradient blue, which is why the transparent frame has a blue background.

Is there any render settings that could be causing this? I feel like it may be a bug, but I wanted to ask if this may be a known feature that I am not understanding.

Edit:
The problem resolves if I disable Motion Blur. So I presume it is some error with my motion blur settings:
Center on Frame, 100.00 Background separation, 32px max blur, and 1 step.
[image]
But I am unsure how this causes an issue.